# Retrieveing Day, Month and Year separately from Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

Is there an implemented way to retrieve separately day, month and year from a Date field in T-SQL? Everything I've found is to make the process the other way around, in my case I mean if I have 2012-05-22 I would like to have 3 different methods to get as a result 2012, 05 and 22 respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database and version? Do you want the string "05" or the number 5?

Comment: @Mark Byers I want the numbers, I'm in MS SQL Server 2008 if that was the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's SQL Server, you can use `DATEPART` (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Example:

```
DECLARE @yourDate DATETIME
SET @yourDate = '2012-05-22'

SELECT DATEPART(DAY, @yourDate), 
       DATEPART(MONTH, @yourDate),
       DATEPART(YEAR, @yourDate)
```

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mssql. You can do this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date=GETDATE()
SELECT
    YEAR(@date) AS Years,
    MONTH(@date) AS MONTHs,
    DAY(@date) AS Days
```

Or you can use `datepart`. Like this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date=GETDATE()
SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR,@date) AS Years,
    DATEPART(MONTH,@date) AS MONTHs,
    DATEPART(DAY,@date) AS Days
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do date_format(DATEFIELD %M) as month, date_format(DATEFIELD %b) as day.

I've used something similar in a Rails application.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: The answer to the question depends on the RDBMS the OP is using - the function you mentioned is MySQL only.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Wrongly assumed it was MySQL!